# Complicated command-line args for executable JAR

Tags: java, command-line, classpath, command-line-arguments, executable-jar

I have a `fizz.jar` that contains a `FizzDriver` class that has a main entry point:

```
public class FizzDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(args.length == 1 && args[0] != null)
            processFile(args[0]);
    }

    // Expects "fileName" to be something like "whatever.log".
    public static void processFile(String fileName) {
        // Process the file
    }
}
```

I have made sure in `MANIFEST.MF` to set `Main-Class` to be my `FizzDriver`.

Now, `fizz.jar` requires 4 other JARs as dependencies:

- `a.jar`
- `b.jar`
- `c.jar`
- `d.jar`

**How do I run `fizz.jar` (`FizzDriver`) from the command-line, while passing it both a file name to process as its sole arg, as well as a classpath that contains my 4 JAR dependencies?**

My best attempt so far has been:

```
java -jar fizz.jar -cp a.jar b.jar c.jar d.jar "whatever.log"
```

But that is not working. Ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Separate the classpath jars with `;` on windows and `:` in linux.

Comment: Thanks @SotiriosDelimanolis (+1) - what about the positioning of `"whatever.log"`? Is it OK to be at the end like that or should it come after `fizz.jar`? And **must** I put the file name in double quotes, or is it OK to leave off the quotes? Thanks again!

Comment: Your best bet is to try it out, but you shouldn't need the quotes.